# File Download pop-up window for excel

Tags: export-to-excel

Hi
I have written a procedure called '`ExportDataTableToExcel(dataTable)`', which accepts a data table and displays all data into an excel worksheet.  However, it doesn't display the 'File Download' pop-up window with `Open/Save/Cancel` options before displaying the excel worksheet.
Any help with required code will be much appreciated.  I am using `ASP.NET` application.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

we do it in Java, but it should work similarly also with ASP.NET

Setting the "Content-Disposition" header should help, if not working try also to set the content type as "application/unknown"

Java Code:

```
response.setHeader( "Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"" );

// If it doesn't work with the line above, add also this one
response.setContentType( "application/unknown" );
```

Comment: Hi Danilo, I tried your Java code to fit into my VB.net code in the following way. But it isn’t working. Please have a look.  Sub btnSubmit_Click()Dim sql As String Dim attachment As String = "attachment; filename=PTW.xlsx" Dim cnn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("xyz")HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment)HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = text/xlsx" cnn.Open()sql = GetReportSql() Dim dt As DataTable() Dim da As SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(sql, cnn) da.Fill(dt)   ExportDataTableToExcel(dt)End Sub Sub ExportDataTableToExcel(ByVal dt As DataTable)End

Comment: sorry I missed your comment... :( Did you try to set the content-type to application/unknown?